# Useless input - logic circuits drawing convention

Tags: digital-logic, diagram

I am a logic circuits beginner.
We are asked to draw a circuit which takes a four-bit word as input, and outputs true if the word is greater than or equal to 10.
Symbolizing the word as (b1b2b3b4), this translates to (b1 | b2 | b3).

Now b4 is completely useless in the circuit. What is the drawing convention for a completely useless input? Do I leave it utterly disconnected, which feels weird, or do I have to go through the hassle of inverting it, ORing itself with its inversion, and ANDing that to the rest of the circuit? Or something else I haven't thought of?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Firstly, it's conventional to number bits like digits, from the right, and from zero:

```
b3 b2 b1 b0
```

Secondly, you should test your circuit with some testcases, as it doesn't act as a >=10 comparator. For example, it reports true for 9 (1001 binary).

Thirdly, you can just leave things disconnected. I've sometimes seen the convention of drawing an X on the end to indicate "deliberately disconnected output". Disconnected *inputs* are considered bad and should be tied to 1 or 0.

Comment: Thanks for the input, how do I represent a connection to 1 or 0, if I draw just this tiny classroom circuit without any "outside world" tied to it, and especially not ground and V?

Comment: Sorry, I may have confused you by using "input" and "output" in the Verilog sense, as seen from outside the unit. So signals coming into a block should be set to something on the _outside_. Within the block, if you're ignoring an input, just leave it.

Comment: X is usually used to denote "don't care" inputs

Comment: I'd caution your first paragraph... I've used more than one 16-bit processor that uses b0=msb and b15=lsb.  I've learnt the hard way not to assume bit ordering, and insist it is stated!

Answer (score 1):

You don't say if your 10 is a decimal Ten or a Binary value = decimal two.  I'll assume the former.  Ten = 1010 which DOES require the 4th input.  If the questions was greater than or equal to 7 you'd be right in not needing that input.

b<3:0> is another representation.

a 4 bit value is also known as a nybble

Comment: I'm assuming from his description that b1 = msb, b4 = lsb